# Two divs appear to have the same height but on calculation, do not

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to connect these two boxes with a line that goes from one to the other.

My solution is calculate 'nodes' on the middle of each of the four edges of each div and then compare the distance to find the two nodes that are the closest to each other.

But, I have an issue:

[image: Two divs with seemingly equal heights but perhaps not?]

The screenshot above shows the two divs which appear to be the same height but the bottom node is showing up incorrect on the first one.

Here is the JS that calculates the 'nodes':

```
var position = $(this).position();
var width = $(this).outerWidth();
var height = $(this).outerHeight();

var step_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('step-', '');

var left = position.left - parseInt($('#steps-canvas').css('padding-left'));
var top = position.top;


// Create nodes clockwise from top-left
nodes[step_id] = [
  [left + (width / 2), top], // Top edge
  [left + width, top + (height / 2)], // Right edge
  [left + (width / 2), top + height], // Bottom edge
  [left, top + (height / 2)] // Left edge
];
```

and here is the result:

[image: The node coordinates for each div]

I'm very perplexed as to why the bottom node for the second div (#2 in the array) is ok but the first is out (by 18px it seems).

Any ideas for the discrepancy? The issue appears in other areas of the project but I can't seem to identify a pattern.

Comment: Can you create a codepen of your code? It's difficult to provide an answer without seeing any markup/example.

Comment: Hmm, very hard to do as there are a lot of elements at play here and it works on certain divs but not on others.

Comment: I have a feeling that the different content in each div is affecting your calculations.  Difficult to prove we cannot see the code in play